# Drawing from a continuous triangular distribution in python Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I make draws and obtain the CDF at certain values `x` from a continuous triangular distribution with `mode=0`, `lower limit=-1` and `upper limit=1`. I could not understand how to set the parameters. I want to get the equivalent of doing `numpyp.random.triangular(left=-1, mode=0, right=1)` in `Scipy`.

I attempted the following but I am not sure if that is what I am after.

`scipy.stats.triang.cdf([-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1], c=0.5, loc=-1, scale=2)` and obtained: `array([ 0, 0.125, 0.5,  0.875, 1.])` which seems correct.

I could not why

`scipy.stats.triang.expect(func=lambda x: x, c = 0.5, loc=0.5, scale=1)`

is producing error message

`_argcheck() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'`

though the `c` argument is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you got the parameters of the CDF function correct.  In general, if you have `left`, `mode` and `right` as used by `numpy.random.triangular`, you can convert those to the parameters of `scipy.stats.triang` using

```
c = (mode - left) / (right - left)
loc = left
scale = right - left
```

---

The arguments of the `expect` method can be confusing.  You tried this:

```
scipy.stats.triang.expect(func=lambda x: x, c = 0.5, loc=0.5, scale=1)
```

The correct call is

```
In [91]: triang.expect(lambda x: x, (0.5,), loc=0.5, scale=1)
Out[91]: 1.0
```

The second argument is a tuple that holds the shape parameters, which in this case is the tuple `(c,)`.  There isn't a separate keyword argument for the shape parameters.

---

To draw samples from a triangular distribution with width 2 centered at 0, use the `rvs` method of `scipy.triang`, with `c=0.5`, `loc=-1`, and `scale=2`.  For example, the following draws 10 samples:

```
In [96]: triang.rvs(c=0.5, loc=-1, scale=2, size=10)
Out[96]: 
array([-0.61654942,  0.03949263,  0.44191603, -0.76464285, -0.5474533 ,
        0.00343265,  0.222072  , -0.14161595,  0.46505966, -0.23557379])
```